# How to I initiate specific spring bean during server start up

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I'm using some support data in my application and I want to load that data at the time of server start. I'm using spring context. If I would be able to load application context at the time of server start up, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Why not listen for a context-initialized event?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the Spring part as I don't use it, but in JSF you can use an [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html)  [`@ManagedBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) whose [`eager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html#eager%28%29) attribtue is set to `true`.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class Data {

    // ...

}
```

This will autoconstruct the managed bean on webapp's startup.

Comment: ApplicationScoped may not work when integrated with Spring, as ViewScoped doesn't.

Comment: @maple_shaft: I've always wondered the usefulness of Spring in Java EE 6.

Comment: @BalusC I agree; JEE6 fixes a lot of issues Spring was created to resolve. That said, Spring includes additional functionality beyond EE6 (which may or may not be required in any given app).

Comment: @DaveNewton I have to agree with Dave.  The benefits of Spring far outweigh the few inconveniences, and the only thing I like about Java EE 6 is JSF.  I just don't trust that Oracle will lead Java in the right direction.

Comment: @maple_shaft Hrm, not sure you're agreeing with me ;) EE6 is nice, and particularly for simple use cases, is arguably a better choice than Spring. The non-tech issues are a different matter entirely, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Register a `ServletContextListener` and fetch the bean in `contextInitialized()` ([see Servlet Life-Cycle Events](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets4.html)).

This has two advantages:

1. You can fetch several beans in a predefined order (this *should* never be necessary but, well, reality always wins)
2. It won't interfere with your tests